# A fire on one end, a fool on the other

Tags: riddle, word

> These are a blight on the whole human race
>   A man is a monkey with one in his face
>   Here's my definition, believe me dear brother:
>   A fire on one end, a fool on the t'other

Source: lyrics of a song by Red Ingle, except I removed the key word. You may have heard it before, if not, you may find it a cute riddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice one.

> Cigarettes
>
> Because you light the one end on fire, and you're the fool on t'other end.

Answer (score 1):

Not an entirely serious answer, but I think it fits!

> Ghost Chilli's, or any chilli that's over 1,000,000 scovilles.

These are a blight on the whole human race

> Too hot chilli's are a blight.  Chilli's should be a reasonable level of hotness.

A man is a monkey with one in his face

> Someone who has eaten one of these chilli's looks like a monkey with their face all screwed up in agony.

A fire on one end, a fool on the t'other

> You have a fire in your rear end if you eat one of these chilli's and you're also a fool if you do.

Comment: yeah, a real blight, the government ought to put warning labels on those things :-)